# Need to change environment values on the fly (they are unknow until building) when building a production angular app

Tags: angular, configuration

When building an angular app using "ng build",  I need to dynamically change the values in the environment.prod.ts file AT THE TIME OF THE BUILD.

export const environment = { valueOfAddress= 'UNKNOWN TILL BUILD" }

ng build -??

Comment: Maybe you need something like this https://medium.com/@natchiketa/angular-cli-and-os-environment-variables-4cfa3b849659

Comment: Yes, that will work. not as easily as I had hoped but that will work. thank you!!